# Do hexadecimal numbers get sign extended if typecast to signed?

Tags: c

I know that hexadecimal numbers are unsigned by default, but what if I typecast them to a signed type?  Do they then get sign extended?

For example (on a system where int is 32bits):

```
signed long l = (signed long)0x81234567;
```

I have 2 different GCC based compilers that act differently here.

Comment: If `long` is 32 bit, then the behavior is implementation defined. If it is 64 bits, then there is nothing to extend.

Comment: Notations like decimal and hexadecimal are not part of the number, they're just part of the string representation of the number. What matters is the value, not how you write it.

Answer (score 1):

From the C17 standard draft (6.3.1.3):

> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.

...

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

This is why your compilers behave differently. A signed long does not have the width to hold that value, so the result is implementation-defined. If that value were just a tad smaller, (less than 2^31-1 == 0x7FFFFFFF == 2,147,483,647), it would be cast(ed)? normally and the value would be retained.